# Laravel middleware limits access to unwanted functions

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I am doing a project in Laravel.
I have a database with posts and users. These posts can be modified and edited by the user who created it and the admin.
To do this I created a new field for users, there is an admin and two editor.
After limiting the access with the middleware, only the admin and editor can access the posts.

```
    $this->middleware('auth',['only' => ['create', 'store', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'roles:admin'],['only' => ['edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);
```

The problem is that now only the admin can access the edit and delete post functions. Publishers are redirected to the home page.

Is there a way to put an if that bypasses the middleware redirect or something similar?

Comment: You should use the Laravel Policy/Gate for that use case. It will gives you more flexibility (like authorize action per resource/ to all resource etc) check it out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Comment: How do you know if the user is the publisher?

Comment: I know that the user is the publisher because the post has its id assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a policy to simplify things, and remove the middleware.

[Create Policy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#generating-policies)

`php artisan make:policy PostPolicy --model=Post`

Resulting in this file

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Post;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Modify the rules for each action, so for example we need to specify that only the admin or the post owner can update a post, so

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
    if ($user->role === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    return $post->user_id === $user->id;
}
```

And then register the policy
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#registering-policies

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Policies\PostPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

And finally authorize your controller, add this line to the constructor

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Post::class, 'post');
}
```

Note that the 2nd parameter in the function call is the name of the route parameter, post is going to be your route parameter if you created the a resourceful controller

If you are not using a resourceful controller, or want to authorize actions manually, then you can use without adding the above line in the constructor

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $post);

   // The current user can update the blog post...
}
```

the first parameter is the name of the policy method, and the 2nd paramter is the post object